# Why do Green Lantern rings recharge every 24 hours if they don't originate on earth?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Generally, Green Lantern rings require recharging every 24 hours.

Why is this? The rings don't originate on earth, so it seems very coincidental that they require recharging every time the earth rotates.

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: If memory serves, the 24 hour thing is a coincidence.

Comment: coincidence, but it's also the average duration of a day on all planets. It could also be specifically linked to the sleep cycle of the wearer since this has changed in the past from being some nebulous exact charge to a 24 charge thing.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the duration of a day on any planet - the ring charges up one hour for each word in the Lanterns' Oath: In Brightest Day, In Blackest Night, No Evil Shall Escape My Sight, Let Those Who Worship Evil's Might Beware My Power, Green Lantern's Light!  (OK, not really - but someone did point out the correlation at one point).

Comment: @RDFozz however, the length of the hour was set by the Babylonians on Earth, whose number system was based on 12 (12 hours day + 12 night = 24 hours).